# How can I add custom visual web part to a site pages

Tags: visual-web-part, sitepages

I want to add custom visual web part to an existing site page. How can I achieve that? Do i need to create feature for that ?

Comment: Deploy that web part through feature (select scope) . Activate the feature. Web Part will be available. You can simply edit page and add a webpart.

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint?